# Проблема с Firebase и новыми версиями Android (API 29, API 30)

Tags: android, firebase

Простенькое приложение берёт данные из Firebase(картинку и два разных текста)

На телефонах Android до 8.0(API 28) приложение работает идеально. На 9.0 и 10.0 (API 29 и 30) показывает только 1 из текстов, картинку не загружает вообще. Что это может быть?

Я начинающий и с такой проблемой столкнулся впервые. Код написал двумя разными способами, но проблема осталась.

При клике на карточку открывается эта же картинка, название и текст рассказа (это в версиях до Android 8.0). В версиях c API 29 и 30 открывается просто пустой экран

В Gradle добавил всё что только можно))

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:20.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:22.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4+'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'

implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:6.3.0'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.5.1'
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.1.1')
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]